# Bash: Search for specific special character in string

Tags: shell

I want to check if special character * is present in my string. I have looked for example but all mentioned about `[^[A..za..z0..9]]..` but this will give u all special characters in string but not exactly a character you are looking for.
So if my string contains `* or [:space:]*` or any character followed by `* (and not /* or */)` then result should be true otherwise false.

```
Ex: 
Uint_8* A
Uint_16 * A
ABC * C    /*blablabla*/
ABC* C .. Should return true  
but 
Uint_8 A       /*blabla*/ ..... should return false
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I have tried this:1.if [ $string= [^[[0-9]|[a-zA-Z]]*] ] then echo "xxx"fi  2. echo $string | awk '\*' '{print NF}' so if string contains * then NF should be 2 if its not then NF should be 1.. but this is not working as it always return 1 if sting contains one * or 1 *. 3. I have also gone through this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767644/bash-test-if-string-has-non-whitespace-characters but smoe how its not helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need is `[^/]\*[^/]`:

For example, if your string is stored in a variable:

```
$ var='Uint_8 A       /*blabla*/'
$ [[ $var =~ [^/]\*[^/] ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

To `grep` matches from a file:

```
$ grep "[^/]\*[^/]" file
Uint_8* A
Uint_16 * A
ABC * C    /*blablabla*/
ABC* C .. Should return true
```

Comment: Note that this will return true for `/* * */`, which is probably unwanted but not specified in the question.